# Swift / UIKit: understanding the structure of built-in methods

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview

I'm new to Swift and `UIKit` and, coming primarily from Python, I'm having trouble with the copy-paste-ness of tutorials and documentation I've been looking at thus far. I'm having a hard time getting a fundamental understanding of methods like:

```
override func tableView( ... numberOfRowsInSection ... )

override func tableView( ... cellForRowAt ... )
```

In practice I can use them without much issue, but I would appreciate any clarification or pointing to references that would explain:

1. Why are `UIKit` methods structured like this, rather than having a dedicated

```
func tableViewNumberOfRowsInSection( ... )
    
func tableViewCellForRowAt( ... )
```

(Or, why not have `numberOfRowsInSection` as an attribute of the subclass of `UITableViewController`, rather than one parameter of a function (tableView) that seems to have hundreds of uses?)

Function/Method basics such as labels, parameter names, etc make perfect sense to me, but I can't seem to make the jump to why func tableView would be structured the way it is.

2. What does the eventual call of tableView look like?

Thanks in advance for any help or pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not the same function used in different ways — they are completely different functions, because the argument labels are part of the functions' names. The full name of each function is `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` and `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` as you can see in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview). You might also want to read the *Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names* section of [this guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html), and maybe the [naming guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#naming).

You are unlikely to call these methods yourself, since they exist to provide data to the table view itself. UITableView will call your methods internally, which would look something like `dataSource.tableView(self, cellForRowAt: indexPath)`. See the *Delegation* section in the [Protocols guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html) for more on this pattern.

It's also worth noting that this API was created for Objective-C (before Swift was released), where their [selectors](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocSelectors.html) are `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. That might be less confusing because the first argument label isn't "privileged" by being outside parentheses. That said, it's still considered a good design by Swift's naming standards, at least as long as the design needs to use classes (which it might not, if it didn't have to support Obj-C).

Answer (score 0):

I won't go into too much detail in this answer, but it is true that delegate methods from UIKit (like the ones you show) tend to be long and near impossible to type out without help from auto-complete.
Nobody I know has memorized all of them (I've tried, and failed).

The reason being is somewhat legacy due to UIKit itself being written in Objective-C by Apple.
If UIKit were to be rewritten in Swift today (*this will never happen due to the huge amount of effort Apple has invested into the framework over the years and the rise of SwiftUI*), it's likely that the API would better follow practices for Swift API design.

To answer your questions specifically:

1. That's the way they've always been–if they were changed at all it would break a lot of developer's source code. Arguably the kind of method signatures you are proposing are not any better, just different. Also, if you read the full method signatures they do make sense and are clear enough.
2. Look into some tutorials for `UITableView`. The methods you are showing off come from `UITableViewDelegate` which is kind of the 'glue' you use to configure the table from your code. This is because back in the early Objective-C days the only way to do this sort of customisation was through this 'delegation pattern'.